# Removing the installation warning from a self hosted Firefox add-on

Tags: firefox-addon

I am self-hosting a Firefox add-on that users can download from my website. When a user clicks to download my Firefox add-on, Firefox displays a warning:

> Firefox prevented this site (example.com) from asking you to install
>   software on your computer.

[image: Firefox add-on installation warning]

Is there a way to prevent the warning from displaying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That popup is there for a reason, it protects users from getting potentially malicious addons without noticing.
Disabling it on your side is not possible afaik.

Comment: There is a second dialog that is even more detailed and warns the user rather explicitly about the potential for damage. Why have two?

Comment: @user967974: To prevent websites from nagging you with these dialogs - if you reject one the site immediately opens another one. Here you will only see a notification that you can ignore if you like.

Comment: I wonder why the browser doesn't implement a policy where the warning only shows when the install is not triggered by a user initiated action much like the policy that most browsers have for popups. This would take care of the scenario you describe without resorting to two scary dialog boxes.

Comment: @user967974: Because websites often want to start an installation automatically (typically: clicking "install" brings you to a web page with installation instructions that starts the installation immediately). Besides, there are plenty of ways to trick the user into clicking something.

Answer (score 4):

This is being controlled by the `xpinstall.whitelist.XXXXXXX` preferences, visible if you go to `about:config`. By default you have `xpinstall.whitelist.add` allowing `addons.mozilla.org` and `xpinstall.whitelist.add.36` allowing `getpersonas.com`. If the user considers your site trustworthy and needs to install extensions from it frequently then he can add another entry for your site. But typically makes more sense to just read the warning and confirm it (or not).